# Implode input field in li tags

Tags: php

I want to display input using implode like:

[image]

**My code :**

```
$qty = array('2', '2', '1');
$price = array('200', '400', '1000');
$subtotal = array('400', '800', '1000');
echo "<li>
Quantity: <input type='text' class='qty' name='qty' value='".implode("'>
Quantity: <input type='text' class='qty' name='qty'   value='",$qty)."'>
Price: <input type='text' class='price' name='price' value='".implode("'>
Price: <input type='text' class='price' name='price' value='",$price)."'>
Subtotal: <input type='text' class='subtot' name='subtot' value='".implode("'>
Subtotal: <input type='text' class='subtot' name='subtot' value='",$subtotal)."'>
</li>";
```

My code has given results:

[image]

**EDIT :**

I want my code should be format like this:

```
<li>
    Quantity: <input ..>
    Price: <input ..>
    Subtotal: <input ..>
<li>
<li>
    Quantity: <input ..>
    Price: <input ..>
    Subtotal: <input ..>
<li>
<li>
    Quantity: <input ..>
    Price: <input ..>
    Subtotal: <input ..>
<li>

...
```

Comment: Please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php. Where is your array for the imploade function ?

Comment: @DineshPatra Code updated.

Comment: if you want to display then explode the arrays and then give their value to your echo.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Could you please use my code do your example on [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)?

Comment: wait.. i am doing for you..

Comment: @FrayneKonok Thank you so much, Can you try with foreach?

Comment: added the foreach loop as well, take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a loop for adding li elements sequentially like this. Try something like below. Following is implemented with the idea of you are using all arrays of same length.

```
$qty = array('2', '2', '1');
$price = array('200', '400', '1000');
$subtotal = array('400', '800', '1000');
for($i = 0; $i < count($qty); $i++) {
    echo "<li>
      Quantity: <input type='text' class='qty' name='qty' value='".$qty[$i]."'>
      Price: <input type='text' class='price' name='price' value='".$price[$i]."'>
      Subtotal: <input type='text' class='subtot' name='subtot' value='".$subtotal[$i]."'>
    </li>";
}
```

**UPDATE with foreach example:**

```
$qty = array('2', '2', '1');
$price = array('200', '400', '1000');
$subtotal = array('400', '800', '1000');
foreach($qty as $key=>$value) {
    echo "<li>
    Quantity: <input type='text' class='qty' name='qty' value='".$qty[$key]."'>
    Price: <input type='text' class='price' name='price' value='".$price[$key]."'>
    Subtotal: <input type='text' class='subtot' name='subtot' value='".$subtotal[$key]."'>
    </li>";
}
```

Comment: Any idea in foreach please?

Comment: absolutely. You just need to use the foreach index in that case. I will update my code.

Comment: @VintageBeef asking people to change a solution to use `foreach` instead of `for` screams [Help Vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem). Please refrain from doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go, this is a pretty simple work, you just go through any of the array, after that just print/ echo the whole li with qty, price, subtotal at a single iteration.

**New Script**

```
<?php
$qty = array('2', '2', '1');
$price = array('200', '400', '1000');
$subtotal = array('400', '800', '1000');
for($i = 0; $i < count($qty); $i++){?>
    <li>
        Quantity: <input type='text' class='qty' name='qty' value='<?php echo $qty[$i];?>'/>
        Price: <input type='text' class='price' name='price' value='<?php echo $price[$i];?>'/>
        Subtotal: <input type='text' class='subtot' name='subtot' value='<?php echo $subtotal[$i];?>'/>
</li>
<?php }?>
```

**Scripts with foreach**

```
<?php
$qty = array('2', '2', '1');
$price = array('200', '400', '1000');
$subtotal = array('400', '800', '1000');
foreach($qty as $key => $value){?>
    <li>
        Quantity: <input type='text' class='qty' name='qty' value='<?php echo $qty[$key];?>'/>
        Price: <input type='text' class='price' name='price' value='<?php echo $price[$key];?>'/>
        Subtotal: <input type='text' class='subtot' name='subtot' value='<?php echo $subtotal[$key];?>'/>
</li>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you submit this in php($_POST) it is already an Array(), you don't have to implode this one anymore.

Comment: $SESSION Not submit.

Comment: are you referring to to `explode()` as i can you you are try to distribute the array values you have? correct me if i'm wrong